# css margin:0 auto does not work in firefox

Tags: css, slider, margin, center, caroufredsel

Please look at the link below in different browsers.
http://www.bayaneqalam.com
The bottom logo slider is located in center of the page in Chrome and IE. But it is in right side in Firefox. What is this problem for ?
I've used **carouFredSel** for this slider.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the applied styles on Firebug? There are some inline styles added to the `.caroufredsel_wrapper` element which doesn't make any sense in some cases.

By the way, there's no `margin: 0 auto;` CSS declaration in the styles. Here's what I got from the Firebug:

```css
element.style {
    bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 100px;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0;        /* <-- the margins of all 4 aspects have been set to 0  */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: auto;
    width: 740px;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

IMO, you could apply the `margin` on the element somewhere in your CSS file, and make sure that it overrides the inline style, as follows:

```css
.caroufredsel_wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hashem. the 2nd part of your code resolved the problem.